# Two different senses of "for"

Tags: prepositions

Consider:

> 1. I checked the car **for** signs of damage.
> 2. They’re spraying **for** mosquitoes this weekend.
>
> -- Entry for **check** and **spray** in macmillan respectively

I think the second **for** means **because of**. It differs from the first **for** which means **in order to get**. Am I right?

Based on this sense of **for**, I made the following sentences:

> They are watering for the dry season next week.
>
> They are cleaning the mansion for the ceremony.
>
> They are blocking the streets for a car accident.
>
> She got a perfect job for a stroke of luck.

Are they all idiomatic for a native speaker? I presume any notional verb can be used with this sense of "for". It's not reserved for a limited number of verbs. Is it true?

Comment: The last two are not logical usages of *for*. And in example 1, *for* also means *because of*, "Because of signs of damage I checked the car."

Comment: I disagree with this assessment.  *Because of* is premised on the knowledge of damage.  When one goes to check *for* signs of damage, the damage is only speculative, and is not necessarily there.  I'd say it's more "*in search of* signs of damage".

Comment: Your sentences are right, but, in my opinion, it would sound more natural if you said. 1. They are watering to prepare for the dry. 2. is ok. 3. They are blocking the streets because of a car accident. 4. She got a perfect job due to a stroke of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many cases the use of "*for*" can be interpreted as "*in search of*" or "*in preparation of*".  This makes the sentence

> They are blocking the streets *for* a car accident.

sound *really funny*, as if *they* are blocking the streets *in anticipation of* an accident, or *to create circumstances* so the accident *can take place*.

> They are watering for the dry season next week. --  preparing, good.
>
> They are cleaning the mansion for the ceremony. -- preparing, fine.
>
> They are blocking the streets for a car accident. -- nope!
>
> She got a perfect job for a stroke of luck. -- nope!

The last sentence does not work for me either (same reason as with *the street blocking*).  Perhaps

> She got a perfect job ***by*** a stroke of luck.

or

> She got a perfect job ***through*** a stroke of luck.

To summarize, in many cases "*for*" means anticipation, preparation.

There is another meaning of "*for*", in which it is a conjunction (not a preposition), it is a shorthand of "*because*". Example:

> Forgive me Father, **for** I have sinned.
> I must have dozed off again, **for** I suddenly jerked awake

Comment: I can add another usage of "for" as : "I (will) do it for you" ! doing something to benefit the other. or "Can you buy a pen for me" . Am I right Victor ?

Comment: Certainly, yes.

Answer (score 0):

No, the "for" in #1

- I checked the car for signs of damage

does not mean *in order to get*.

i can understand your confusion. I searched both Merriam-Webster and Oxford for the appropriate sense of  "for" and couldn't seem to find it, but finally settled on this one:

- Merriam, sense 1(c)

> c —used as a function word to indicate the object or recipient of a perception, desire, or activity 
>   http://i.word.com/idictionary/for

So, "signs of damage" is the *object of an activity* : "checking".

Regarding the "for" in sentence 2: It does not mean *because*. As near as I can tell, it is used in the same sense as above; that is, the mosquitoes are the *object or recipient of an activity*: "spraying".  (Although it does seem odd to spray **for** mosquitos it almost seems that we spray **against** them! Maybe we spray "for to kill'em")

Since neither of your initial examples has the sense of "for" that you imputed to them, your four subsequent suggested sentences are really a separate topic, which Victor Basarov has already dealt with admirably.